# SQL Server loading table using import utility

Tags: sql-server

I need to load a table using a file but need to specify the column properties before loading.

```
Table definition:

id int
name varchar(50)
salary float

Data in the text file

1,BOB,1000
```

When I use the import utility, it defaults all the columns to varchar an considers all the values in the input file as strings.

How do I specify that 1 column is integer, 2nd column should be varchar and 3rd column should be float?

Answer (score 0):

Under the SSIS 'Flat File Source', you see on the left four icons, the third of which is named Advanced.  That's where you set your column types and sizes.

Comment: THanks..How do I get the SQLScript thats being executed by the import utility?